# Rotate and flip using matrix

Tags: android, matrix, bitmap

I have a bitmap I'm trying to rotate 270deg then flip horizontally. My first attempted looked like this.

```
matrix.postRotate (270);
matrix.postTranslate (bitmap.getWidth (), 0);
bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap (bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth (), bitmap.getHeight (), matrix, true);
```

This rotates the bitmap but does not flip it. I then tried this code.

```
matrix.postRotate (270);
matrix.postScale (-1f, 1f);
bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap (bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth (), bitmap.getHeight (), matrix, true);
```

And it works. But why didn't the first one work? Shouldn't translate be used to flip not scale?

Comment: can you post a result picture for both result

Comment: Note that doing this sequence of transformations is equivalent to a transpose (ie a flip on one of the image diagonals, chosen depending on whether you do the rotation clock wise or not).

Comment: does `android.graphics.Matrix` have a transpose method? I couldn't find one.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the image transpose. Does a transposed matrix produce a transposed image? I cannot tell yet.

Comment: The scaling operation will not flip the matrix, it will merely multiply the diagonal coefficients of the matrix by the specified factors, so don't try to use a matrix transpose, you'll get a different result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Translate just shifts the image by a certain amount to another place. It does not flip it. This is like moving a piece of paper on the table.

On the other hand, scaling along one axis by a factor of -1 flips the direction of this axis.